# DataStore does not seem to get the correct boolean value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-datastore

I am attempting to get the boolean value from the datastore. Whenever the player has scored 10 out of 10, a platinum is awarded to the player. However, if the player has scored 10 out of 10 for the second time (or more), then the platinum does not get awarded, as the player has already received it (or in essence, unlocked it).

There are a few problems:

1. Whenever the player scores 10 out of 10, then the "textview_platinumMessage" is set to "Already achieved!". Notwithstanding that, the platinum gets awarded.
2. When the player scores 10 out of 10 the second time, it seems to work fine.
3. However, when the user closes the app, and the player scores 10 out of 10 for the third (or more) time, the platinum gets awarded, and the message says "You have been awarded 1 Platinum. Congratulations!", when it should have been "Already achieved!".

Code to determine if the platinum has already been earned in previous attempts.

```
class endOfGameScreen: AppCompatActivity {

    lateinit var boolean_platinumIsEarned = false
    
    lateinit var singlePlayerPlatinumManager: singlePlayerPlatinumManager
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_completed)
        
        getBackendData()
    }

    fun getBackendData(){
        
        singlePlayerPlatinumManager = singlePlayerPlatinumManager(this)

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            boolean_platinumIsEarned = singlePlayerPlatinumManager.getLevelOnePlatinumBall.first()
        }

        setInGameCurrencyScoresToEndScreen()
    }

    fun setInGameCurrencyScoresToEndScreen(){

        if (int_correctAnswers == int_totalNumberOfQuestions) {
            textview_status.setText("CONGRATULATIONS!")
            icon_platinum.setImageResource(R.drawable.platinum)
            
            singlePlayerPlatinumManager.getLevelOnePlatinumBall.asLiveData().observe(this) {
                if (boolean_platinumIsEarned == true) {
                    textview_platinumMessage.setText("Already achieved!")
                } else {
                    int_platinumToBeAwarded = 1
                    textview_platinumMessage.setText("You have been awarded 1 Platinum. Congratulations!")
                    GlobalScope.launch {
                        gameCurrencyManager.setPlatinum(int_currentPlatinumTotal + int_platinumToBeAwarded)
                        singlePlayerPlatinumManager.setLevelOnePlatinumBall(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code for the datastore preferences for platinum being awarded. I am not sure if there is anything wrong here, bearing in mind that I have made similar datastore preferences classes, but for integer values.

```
private val Context.singlePlayerPlatinumManager by preferencesDataStore("single_player_platinum_manager")

class singlePlayerPlatinumManager(context: Context) {

    private val singlePlayerPlatinumManager = context.singlePlayerPlatinumManager

    companion object{
        val LEVEL_ONE_PLATINUM_BALL_KEY = booleanPreferencesKey("LEVEL_ONE_PLATINUM_KEY")
        //.
    }

    //SETTER
    suspend fun setLevelOnePlatinum(boolean_levelOnePlatinum: Boolean){
        singlePlayerLevelPlatinumManager.edit{
            it[LEVEL_ONE_PLATINUM_KEY] = boolean_levelOnePlatinumBall
        }
    }

    //GETTER
    val getLevelOnePlatinum: Flow<Boolean> = singlePlayerLevelPlatinumManager.data.map{
        it[LEVEL_ONE_PLATINUM_KEY] ?: false
    }
}
```

Comment: The key piece of code we need to see is where you are creating and initializing `boolean_platinumIsEarned` from the `getLevelOnePlatinum` flow. Is your first block of code within or called from the collector?

Comment: I have created the boolean_platinumIsEarned above the class. I then initialised it in the function/method "getBackendData". I have edited this post, and I should have made it clear before hand.

Comment: You’re launching a coroutine to get the value from the flow. Then you immediately proceed with trying to use the value before the coroutine has had a chance to update it. If you move your call to `setInGameCurrencyScoresToEndScreen` inside the coroutine, the issue will be resolved. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o) for more info.